# Why I Don't find Skipped Stages in Spark Dataset execution

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to understand spark execution in case of Dataset.

For RDD i found below in Spark Docs -

> Shuffle also generates a large number of intermediate files on disk. As of Spark 1.3, these files are preserved until the corresponding RDDs are no longer used and are garbage collected. This is done so the shuffle files don’t need to be re-created if the lineage is re-computed.

I tried running similar thing with RDD and Dataset, i don't find skipped stages in case Dataset execution which I get in RDD.Is there any hint i need to do in code for preserving shuffle.I mean i want dataset should share shuffle files between jobs. If I convert Dataset to RDD and then again back to Dataset I can see skipped stages(I am using spark 2.3)

```
Dataset<Long> rangeDs = session.range(0L, 2000000L);
Dataset<Tuple2<Long,Long>> rangePairDsGbk =  rangeDs.groupByKey(new 
MapFunction<Long, Long>(){

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Override
public Long call(Long value) throws Exception {
    return value;
}
}, Encoders.LONG()).reduceGroups(new ReduceFunction<Long>() {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Override
public Long call(Long v1, Long v2) throws Exception {
    return 1L;
}
});
rangePairDsGbk.count(); //Full Re-Computation
rangePairDsGbk.count();//Full Re-Computation (why this job is doing Full Re- 
computation)

JavaRDD<Long> rangeRdd = session.range(0L, 2000000L).toJavaRDD();
JavaPairRDD<Long, Long> rangePairRddRbk = rangeRdd.mapToPair(new 
PairFunction<Long, Long, Long>() {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Override
public Tuple2<Long, Long> call(Long t) throws Exception {
    return new Tuple2<Long, Long>(t, t);
}
}).reduceByKey(new Function2<Long, Long, Long>() {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Override
public Long call(Long v1, Long v2) throws Exception {
    return 1L;
}
}, 200);
rangePairRddRbk.count();//Full Re-Computation
rangePairRddRbk.count();//Partial Re-Computation (Only Shuffle Read as 
Expected)
```

Comment: still waiting for reply..